# Select all where sender sent 5 or more messages to 5 or more different targets

Tags: mysql

Help with query please.
Need to select all senders who sent 5 or more messages from "**sender_id**" to 5   or more different "**target_id**"

## SQL Table:

```
**sender_id - target_id**<br>  
1 - 2 
1 - 2
1 - 2
1 - 2
1 - 3
1 - 4
1 - 24
1 - 5
2 - 5
...
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select sender_id,count(Distinct target_id) from table 
Group by sender_id 
Having count(Distinct target_id) >= 5
```

use MySQL `group by` with `Count Distinct` record